# C++11/14 how to create async task using function that return type is void or others

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I want to write a simple task class that similar to ppltasks.

I want my task class can create task as following:

```
1.CreateTask([=]{}).then([=]{...});
2.CreateTask([=]{ return X; }).then([=](UnknownType X){...});
```

But the function I want to run in task may have different type:void, float, string etc. And here is the key point:

```
auto val = func();    // If func is a void function
prms->set_value(val); // here should be: func(); prms->set_value();
```

How can I handle void function and other type function using same CreateTask?

Following is my full code of task class:

```
template<typename TType>
class Task
{
public:
    Task(){};
    std::future<TType> mTask;
    template<typename F>
    auto then(F func)->Task<decltype(func(mTask.get()))>
    {
        Task<decltype(func(mTask.get()))> task;
        auto prms = make_shared<promise<decltype(func(mTask.get()))>>();
        task.mTask = prms->get_future();
        thread th([=]
        {
            auto val = func(mTask.get()); //
            prms->set_value(val);
        });
        th.detach();
        return task;
    });
};

inline void CreateTask(F func) -> Task<decltype(func())>
{
    Task<decltype(func())> task;
    auto prms = make_shared<promise<decltype(func())>>();
    task.mTask = prms->get_future();
    thread th([=] 
    {
        auto val = func();
        prms->set_value(val);
    });
    th.detach();
    return task;
}
```

Comment: By adding tons and tons of tag-dispatching code. In C++17 it gets somewhat easier due to `if constexpr`. But this is a [known problem](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/p0146r1.html) with no good solution.

Comment: @nwp tonnes and tonnes?

Comment: @Yakk Yeah. In practice you will have multiple functions and triple redundancy for each one. It's hard to see the code in all the boiler-plate like you demonstrated. It can make sense to try to not support `void` return types in order to be able to maintain the code afterwards.

Comment: @nwp most of that is because I'm paranoid and tossed in an insane amount of corner-case handling.  Simplified version added.  It isn't tonnes and tonnes of tag-dispatching; it is exactly one tag-dispatch.  You can simplify it further if you only are using it once.

Comment: `inline void CreateTask(F func) -> Task<decltype(func())>` -- do you mean to use `auto` not `void`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets attack this via separation of concerns.

First, the problem of pipeing the output of one invokable to another:

```
template<class Index>
auto get_nth( Index ) {
  return [](auto&&...args)noexcept(true)->decltype(auto) {
    return std::get<Index::value>(
      std::forward_as_tuple( decltype(args)(args)... )
    );
  };
}

template<class F>
struct pipeable_t;

template<class F>
pipeable_t<std::decay_t<F>> make_pipe(F&&);

struct is_pipeable {
    template<
        class Lhs, class Rhs,
        std::enable_if_t< 
            std::is_base_of<is_pipeable, std::decay_t<Lhs>>{}
            || std::is_base_of<is_pipeable, std::decay_t<Rhs>>{}
        , int> = 0
    >
    friend
    auto operator|( Lhs&& lhs, Rhs&& rhs ) {
        auto pipe_result=
            [lhs = std::forward<Lhs>(lhs), rhs=std::forward<Rhs>(rhs)]
            (auto&&...args)mutable ->decltype(auto) 
            {
                auto value_is_void = std::is_same< decltype( lhs(decltype(args)(args)...) ), void >{};
                auto pipe_chooser = get_nth( value_is_void );
                auto pipe_execution = pipe_chooser(
                    [&](auto&& lhs, auto&& rhs)->decltype(auto){ return rhs( lhs( decltype(args)(args)... ) ); },
                    [&](auto&& lhs, auto&& rhs)->decltype(auto){ lhs( decltype(args)(args)... ); return rhs(); }
                );
                return pipe_execution( lhs, rhs );
            };
        return make_pipe( std::move(pipe_result) );
    }
};

template<class F>
struct pipeable_t:is_pipeable {
    F f;
    pipeable_t( F fin ):f(std::forward<F>(fin)) {}
    template<class...Args>
    auto operator()(Args&&...args) const {
        return f( std::forward<Args>(args)... );
    }
    template<class...Args>
    auto operator()(Args&&...args) {
        return f( std::forward<Args>(args)... );
    }
};

template<class F>
pipeable_t<std::decay_t<F>> make_pipe(F&& f) { return {std::forward<F>(f)}; }

template<class T>
auto future_to_factory( std::future<T>&& f ) {
    return [f=std::move(f)]() mutable { return f.get(); };
}

template<class T>
auto make_pipe( std::future<T>&& f ) {
    return make_pipe( future_to_factory( std::move(f) ) );
}
```

we can `make_pipe( some lambda )` and it can now be fed into more stuff.

A pipe is executable and pipeable itself.  We can make anything executable a pipe, and we can make a `std::future` into a pipe.

Once we have this, we rewrite your `Task` in terms of it:

```
struct dispatch_via_async {
    template<class F>
    auto operator()(F&& f)const {
        return std::async( std::launch::async, std::forward<F>(f) );
    }
};

template<class T, class Dispatch=dispatch_via_async>
class Task;

template<class F, class D=dispatch_via_async>
using task_type = Task<std::decay_t<std::result_of_t<F&&()>>, D>;

template<class F, class D=dispatch_via_async>
task_type<F, D> CreateTask(F&& func, D&& d={});

template<class T, class Dispatch>
class Task :
    public is_pipeable, // why not?
    private Dispatch
{
    std::future<T> mTask;

    Dispatch& my_dispatch() { return *this; }
public:
    T operator()() { return mTask.get(); }
    Task(){};
    template<class F>
    auto then(F&& func)&&
    {
        return CreateTask(
          make_pipe(std::move(mTask)) | std::forward<F>(func),
          std::move(my_dispatch())
        );
    }

    template<class F, class D=Dispatch>
    explicit Task( F&& func, D&& dispatch={} ):
        Dispatch(std::forward<D>(dispatch))
    {
        mTask = my_dispatch()(
            [func = std::forward<F>(func)]() mutable
            -> decltype(func())
            {
                return func();
            }
        );
    }
};

template<class F, class D>
task_type<F,D> CreateTask(F&& func, D&& d)
{
    return task_type<F,D>( std::forward<F>(func), std::forward<D>(d) );
}
```

Here we carefully permit the dispatcher (how we get the future) to be passed into a `Task` if required.  The `.then`'d continuations will use the dispatcher to create the chained futures.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f44189ff99d2336d).

As a bonus, you now have a simple streaming chain-of-operations library.

Note that I replaced your `thread` based implementation with an `async` based one, because your system failed to properly wait for threads to terminate before program finished, which leads to undefined behavior.  You can still replace that `Dispatcher` with one that uses threads.

---

In [c++2a](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b2a), [Regular Void](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/p0146r1.html) proposal attempts to get rid of the problem.  I don't know how well it does the job.

---

The above doesn't build in current versions of MSVC because MSVC fails to be a proper [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) compiler in that its async uses packaged task, its packaged task stores its tasks in a std function, which results in the async incorrectly requiring that the task being called by *copyable* as `std::function` type-erases copy.

This breaks the above code because we store a `std::future` in our async tasks, which cannot be copied.

We can fix this for a modest cost.  The minimal most isolated way to do it is to change `future_to_factory` to:

```
template<class T>
auto future_to_factory( std::future<T>&& f ) {
    return [f=std::make_shared<std::future<T>>(std::move(f))]() mutable { return f->get(); };
}
```

and the code [compiles on visual studio](http://rextester.com/FNOFH65607).

Comment: A nice solution IMHO :). Just a small caveat I ran into trying it out myself: If you want it to run "asynchronously" I found that you have to save the object returned by `CreateTask` (`auto task = CreateTask(...).then(...);`). Else, the destructor of `std::future` will block, as we are using `std::async`. This is, however, not a big deal.

Comment: @Yakk The live example failed to compile in visual studio neither nor in xcode.

Comment: @Yonghui Fixed an issue that breaks clang (and should break).  Visual Studio is harder, as it is not really a [tag:C++14] compiler.

Comment: @Yonghui Reading the error messages when I tried it on an online VS compiler, it appears that MSVC's `packaged_task` (which is move-only under the standard) uses `function` internally, which in turn expects its callables to be *copyable*.  And their `std::async` in turn uses `packaged_task`.  The above code uses non-copyable callables to pass to `async` (because there is no need to copy them); in particular, it stores a `std::future<T>` to be `.get`'d in another thread.

Comment: @Yonghui A slight modification to one function makes it compile in visual studio.  Live link added demonstrating it.  I also made the code clang++ compliant; I don't know if I used stuff beyond what the clang++ that xcode uses (which I think is up to code based on clang 4.0)